# JQuery selector exclusion logic not working

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of  elements with the **href** value of **#slider-5**, **#slider-6**, **#slider-7**, and so on. There are also a bunch of other  elements with **href** values containing **#** but in a different pattern. I want to write a selector logic that targets only the second kind of  elements, i.e. those that contain **#** in their **href** but not the combination **#slider**. This is what I wrote:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#], [href=#slider])')
```

However, this logic doesn't seem to honor the **#slider** exclusion logic.

What I need is for it to pick all  tags that *contain* *#*, but exclude the below:

- contains *only* **#**, and
- contains **#** followed by the word **slider**

Comment: Instead of telling you have a "bunch of elements" and a "bunch of elements", please post a [mcve]

Comment: The value in the equality selector should be in quotes https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: Thanks for at least trying to help, Phil. But the issue persists despite the quotes. $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"], [href="#slider"])')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use selector: `$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"], [href^="#slider"])')`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to implement some strange CSS selector, use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to filter elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a')
    .filter(function() {
      return $(this).attr('href').indexOf('#slider-') == 0;
    })
    .addClass('selected');
})
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.selected {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#slider-1">Slider-1</a><br/>
<a href="#slider-2">Slider-2</a><br/>
<a href="#slider">Slider</a><br/>
<a href="#">#</a>
```